# Canceling the emission sequence with Observables RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm creating a thread to control mouse directions (pixel by pixel) using javascript. Sometimes I need to stop the mouse movement and give it a new direction (a set of pixels). I would like to use Observables.

I would like to output the pixel sequences, for example:
[(x0, x0), ..., (xN, yN), (x1, y1)]

If a new set of pixels is issued, the previous one will be cleaned.

I would like to know the best way to do this, which operators, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are emitting a "sequence" as an array of "points", something like this should work:

```js
type Point = [number, number];

const DELAY = 200;
const pixelSequence$ = new Subject<Point[]>();

const mousePoint$ = pixelSequence$.pipe(
  switchMap(sequence => timer(0, DELAY).pipe(
    map(i => sequence[i]),
    take(sequence.length),
  ))
);

mousePoint$.subscribe(
  ([x, y]) => setMousePosition(x, y)
);
```

Here we start with a Subject that will emit a "pixel sequence" (`Point[]`).  We can define a new Observable that will emit individual points, then subscribe to that observable to set the cursor position:

```js
mousePoint$.subscribe(
  ([x, y]) => setMousePosition(x, y)
);
```

The core of the functionality happens in the definition of `mousePoint$`.  We define a new Observable that begins when `pixelSequence$` emits a value.  We then use `switchMap` and create an "inner observable" that emits the sequence items one at a time at with the specified DELAY inbetween.

```js
  switchMap(sequence => timer(0, DELAY).pipe(
    map(i => sequence[i]),
    take(sequence.length),
  ))
```

If you aren't familiar with `switchMap`, it basically receives a emission as input, then subscribes to an "inner observable" for you, emitting its emissions.  When `switchMap` receives a new emission, it will "switch" its inner source to a new observable, unsubscribing from its previous "inner observable".

So, to begin your mouse moving, simply call `pixelSequence$.next()` with an array of coorinates.  If you need to use a different sequence (*whether or not the current sequence has been fully processed*), simply call `pixelSequence$.next()` again with the new sequence.

Here is a [example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73251140?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).

### Operators used:

- `switchMap` - subscribe to inner observable and emit its emissions
- `timer` - emit sequential integers at the specified interval
- `map` - transform each emission with the provided function
- `take` - complete the observable when the specified number of emissions have been received

Comment: Working like a charm! Ez for @BizzyBob :)

Comment: Is the code appropriate for sequences that will happen continuously? I mean, the mouse never stops.